# $\dim (W_{1} \cap W_{2}) = \dim W_{1}$ implies $W_{1} \subset W_{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $W_{1}, W_{2}$ be subspaces of $V$. If $\dim (W_{1} \cap W_{2}) = \dim W_{1}$, must $W_{1} \subset W_{2}$?

Since $\dim (W_{1} \cap W_{2}) = \dim W_{1},$ every basis $\alpha \subset W_{1} \cap W_{2}$ has the same number of vectors as every basis $\beta \subset W_{1}$. If $W_{1} \not\subset W_{2}$, then there is a $v \in W_{1} \setminus W_{2}.$ Hitherto I can only tell that $v \notin$ span$(\alpha)$ and cannot proceed. I would like to see how this can proceed.

Comment: You mean $β ⊂ W_1$.

Comment: Thanks. What a gross typo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if $A \subset B$ are vector spaces with $\dim A = \dim B < \infty$ then $A = B$

Answer (score 3):

No need to reason about bases here. The intersection $W_1\cap W_2$ of two subspaces is always a subspace of $W_1$ (and also of $W_2$ but that won't be used here). If in addition it has the same (finite) dimension as $W_1$, then it must be all of $W_1$, that is $W_1\cap W_2=W_1$. But that means that $W_1\subseteq W_2$.

Comment: I think there is very much need to reason about bases. The statement doesn’t hold if you replace vector spaces with free modules and dimensions with rank, or if you go to the infinite-dimensional. You strongly use the fact that bases of finitely generated vector spaces have a unique length and are characterized by being maximal linearly independent systems. The answer you have given just subsumes all that in the step “If in addition it has the same (finite) dimension as $W_1$, then it must be all of $W_1$”.

Comment: @k.stm: Think of the level as which OP when posing this question. Clearly this is an introductory course on linear algebra, where the notion of dimension has been seen, probably only the finite dimensional case. Then among the fundamental properties are that the dimensions of subspaces of (finite dimensional) $V$ are integers between $0$ and $\dim V$, and that for the extremal cases there is exactly one subspace of given dimension (which is $V$ for $\dim V$), more in the other cases. That uses bases. But once this is known there is no reason to use bases _rather_ than applying this known fact.

Comment: ... Note that OP (currently) accepted an answer that does nothing more than just recall this fact, without even mentioning how it can be applied in the current situation. I know lots more about these things, like that it still works for modules over a division ring, but not for vector spaces of infinite dimension, nor even in finite rank for modules over general commutative rings, but I don't think that OP really needs to be bothered which such facts. (S)he just needs to be reminded of how to _apply_ things that are assumed to be known at that level.

Comment: I didn’t mean to question your competence on linear algebra. To me it seemed like the problem was meant to exercise how to handle bases and base lengths and reason with them.  From this point of view, I merely found “no need to reason about bases” to be false. That the questioner accepted the hint-answer, on the other hand, speaks for your interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

If $\dim W_1 ∩ W_2 = \dim W_1$, then every basis of $W_1 ∩ W_2$ already is a basis of $W_1$, because it’s a linearly independent system in $W_1$ of the correct length, viz $\dim W_1$. If $α$ is such a basis, then $W_1 ∩ W_2 = \mathrm{span} (α) = W_1$, and from $W_1 ∩ W_2 = W_1$ you can conclude $W_1 ⊂ W_2$.